# Why doesn't the src attribute of inner html recognize my dynamically-generated variable?

Tags: javascript, php, parameter-passing

I have dynamically generated (via php) a list of videos, each of which belongs to a different user with a profile picture ('userpic'). I am able to pass the 'userpic' to a javascript function 'video' called within the php as follows in this **first echo statement**:

```
<?php
//Lots of code
echo "<script>
function video(userpic) {
function AnotherFunction();
document.getElementById('UserPicHolder').innerHTML = userpic;
}
</script>";
//Lots of code
?>
```

Function 'video' calls AnotherFunction (works great). The path for var = userpic is the correct local path and displays correctly in the correct div ('UserPicHolder'). Everything works fine....then I change the inner HTML to an image attribute as follows:

```
<?php
//Lots of code
echo "<script>
function video(userpic) {
function AnotherFunction();
document.getElementById('UserPicHolder').innerHTML = '<img src=\"userpic\"    
style=\"width:50px; height:55px\" alt=\"user picture\" class=\"SomeClass\" 
title=\"Some text\">';
}
</script>";
//Lots of code
?>
```

In this **second echo statement**, even though the path is clearly correct as shown in the **first echo statement**, the image just does not display in 'UserPicHolder'. I have replaced userpic in the src with a local path and the icon displays correctly (in this third echo statement):

```
<?php
//Lots of code
echo "<script>
function video(userpic) {
function AnotherFunction();
document.getElementById('UserPicHolder').innerHTML = '<img src=\"images/icon.jpg\"    
style=\"width:50px; height:55px\" alt=\"user picture\" class=\"SomeClass\" 
title=\"Some text\">';
}
</script>";
//Lots of code
?>
```

Why is userpic in the **second echo statement** not being identifed in the inner HTML img src? Note I have also replaced (just guessing at this point after reading other posts) src=\"userpic\" with src=\"".userpic."\" and src=\""+userpic+"\" and src=\"+userpic+\" and src=\"".+userpic+."\" to no avail.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is space between `<?` and `php` on your code. I wonder how your code executes ? O.o

Comment: That's just a typo...sorry. I will edit.

Comment: I suppose the HTML with the element `UserPicHolder` is sent before this javascript runs, right? Otherwise it won't exists and `document.getElementById()` will return `undefined`.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some real code instead of this pseudo approach to your problem. We cannot help you with this syntactically incoherent crap.

Comment: Wow....just relax @Havenard. As I mentioned the only problems were I was tired and I did not know how to concatenate this properly. Sorry about my crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be `src=\"'+userpic+'\"`, as in:

```
document.getElementById('UserPicHolder').innerHTML = '<img src=\"'+userpic+'\" style=\"width:50px; height:55px\" alt=\"user picture\" class=\"SomeClass\" title=\"Some text\">';
```

That is because `userpic` is a JS variable and therefore needs to be concatenated with the rest of the string.  The first part of the string is `'<img src=\"'`, then you add the variable and then `'\" style=\"width:50px; height:55px\" alt=\"user picture\" class=\"SomeClass\" title=\"Some text\">'`

That all being said, why do you echo one long string and don't just exit out of PHP, like this:

```
<?php
//Lots of code
?>
<script>
    function video(userpic) {
        function AnotherFunction();
        document.getElementById('UserPicHolder').innerHTML = '<img src="'+userpic+'">';
    }
</script>
<?php
//Lots of code
?>
```

Comment: Awesome....thank you very much @Steve! I knew I was close but I just couldn't get it (maybe staring at the code for 2 hours didn't help either :)   ). Thanks again...your answer worked right away.

Comment: Yes, this worked too @Steve. I originally was going to do this but when I started making progress with the script in the php (the script was moved into the php portion of the page based on a prior erroneous conclusion when the script was in the html <head>) in what I was trying to do I just kept the code in the php instead of moving it back to the <head>. Any advantages to one over the other? e.g. Is one method faster?

Answer (score 0):

you are not correctly changing the `innerHTML` here:

```
document.getElementById('UserPicHolder').innerHTML = '<img src=\"userpic\"    
style=\"width:50px; height:55px\" alt=\"user picture\" class=\"SomeClass\" 
title=\"Some text\">';
```

this will make the `src` = `userpic` at all times

to chage it dynamically use the concatenation operator `+` and change the code to :

```
document.getElementById('UserPicHolder').innerHTML = '<img src=\"'+userpic+"\"    
style=\"width:50px; height:55px\" alt=\"user picture\" class=\"SomeClass\" 
title=\"Some text\">';
```